# Displaying popover after clicking on an event in react-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-big-calendar

I created the `Event ()` function that it passes as a custom component to

```
<Calendar components = {{
   event: Event
}}/>
```

Then in the `Event ()` function I create the variable `popoverClickRootClose`, in which I place the react-bootstrap`popover`. Then `popoverClickRootClose` passes to the component:

```
<OverlayTrigger overlay = {popoverClickRootClose}>
     <div> {event.title}</ div>
</ OverlayTrigger>
```

After clicking in the event no popover appears. Could someone advise me what I am doing wrong?

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-umtvgs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import {Overlay} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {OverlayTrigger} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Popover} from 'react-bootstrap';

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

function Event({ event }) {
  let popoverClickRootClose = (
    <Popover id="popover-trigger-click-root-close" style={{ zIndex: 10000 }}>
      <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.
      <strong>{event.title}</strong>
    </Popover>
  );

  console.log(event);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <OverlayTrigger id="help" trigger="click" rootClose container={this} placement="bottom" overlay={popoverClickRootClose}>
          <div>{event.title}</div>
        </OverlayTrigger>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    const now = new Date();
    const events = [
      {
          id: 0,
          title: 'All Day Event very long title',
          allDay: true,
          start: new Date(2019, 6, 0),
          end: new Date(2019, 6, 1),
          description: 'sdsdsdsdsdsdsdsd'
      },
      {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: new Date(2019, 3, 7),
          end: new Date(2019, 3, 10),
          description: 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Right now Time Event',
          start: now,
          end: now,
          description: 'cddffffffffdfdfdfd'
      },
    ]
    this.state = {
      events
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ height: '500pt'}}>
          <Calendar
            events={this.state.events}
            startAccessor="start"
            endAccessor="end"
            defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
            localizer={localizer}
             components={{
              event: Event
            }}
          />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: [Working Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pcr9hh?file=index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no issue with the Javascript code you posted. It's a CSS issue**

You have included multiple bootstrap css  versions (**bootstrap 4 and 3**) and the `react-bootstrap` package version is `0.32` which works well, only with **bootstrap 3**

**Remove** bootstrap `4.3.1` reference from the html as its not compatible with the react-bootstrap package you are using.

Change..

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
```

to

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
```

I have added the working stackblitz link as a comment.