# Modifying the tooltip in react-big-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

How to modify the tooltip that appears when you hover over an event? I would like to include more information (start date, end date,  id, buttons(edit, delete). I tried:

```
function Event({ event }) {
  return (
    <span>
      <strong>{event.title}</strong>
      {event.desc && ':  ' + event.desc}
    </span>
  )
}

 <Calendar
    events={events}
    localizer={localizer}
    defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 1)}
    components={{
      event: Event
    }}
  />
```

but this only changes the event and not the tooltip that appears when you hover over the event. Is modifying the tooltip possible at all?

Comment: Isn't this solved with my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538528/displaying-popover-after-clicking-on-an-event-in-react-big-calendar) ?

Comment: @nithin Prevoius question was click on event. Here is hover on event

Comment: Ok. Let me take a look.

Comment: This might help [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/big-calendar-demo-qrghkn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Looks like the Event tooltip is not customizable in  `react-big-calendar`**

As you have a custom `Event` component and if you are using bootstrap, you can try to achieve this  using [Overlay](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.com/components/overlays/) and [Tooltip](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.com/components/tooltips/) from `react-bootstrap`.

**Things get tricky as overlays/tooltips close as soon as you move away from the target element**.

As your tooltip contains **delete**, **edit** buttons, you need to have some logic to make the tooltip **stay on screen** and handle **when to close** the tooltip.

A sample implementation below..

> Opens tooltip on mouseover  event.
>
> Closes tooltip on click of close button inside tooltip.
>
> Closes tooltip on click anywhere outside tooltip (including the target).

BTW I don't see this as a good solution, but can be a head start.

```
const IconStyle = {
  cursor: "pointer"
};

const TooltipContent = ({ onClose, event }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={faWindowClose}
        className="pull-right"
        style={IconStyle}
        onClick={onClose}
      />
      <div>{event.title}</div>
      <div>Some other Info</div>
      <Row>
        <Button variant="light">Button 1</Button>
        <Button variant="light">Button 2</Button>
      </Row>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

function Event(event) {
  const [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = useState(false);

  const closeTooltip = () => {
    setShowTooltip(false);
  };

  const openTooltip = () => {
    setShowTooltip(true);
  };
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const getTarget = () => {
    return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(ref.current);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <span onMouseOver={openTooltip}>{event.title}</span>
      <Overlay
        rootClose
        target={getTarget}
        show={showTooltip}
        placement="top"
        onHide={closeTooltip}
      >
        <Tooltip id="test">
          <TooltipContent event={event} onClose={closeTooltip} />
        </Tooltip>
      </Overlay>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have added a stackblitz demo as comment

Comment: [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/big-calendar-demo-qrghkn) is the demo from the comments on the question if anyone needs it

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom event component, you can just set `tooltipAccessor={null}` in calendar props to disable default calendar tooltip and add regular HTML title attribute with the information you need on HTML element in your custom event component.

For eg.

```html
<div title="Some text">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, `null` is not a valid value for tooltipAccessor property. Setting that property to an empty string is what ultimately worked (and is valid by the component)

Answer (score 1):

This is issue solved with this [PR](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/pull/701)

Adding this prop solved my problem. You can modify empty string if you want to show something else.

```
<Calendar tooltipAccessor={() => ""} ... />
```