# Return JSX element to string required function in react

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, react-big-calendar

I'm using [React big calendar](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#api) in there ***tooltipAccessor*** require a string, But i needs to add more data into tooltip according to some UI formatting (as in the image).

Is there anyway to pass JSX as a string.

[image]

Comment: You can pass an object of jsx element's info, and that's all the content you would need for an element. Refer to official document https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: I'll try this...

Comment: Try this [modifying tooltip in react big calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58605394/modifying-the-tooltip-in-react-big-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution.

There is an ***component*** API option to pass a custom component to the calendar. so you can access ***eventWrapper - capable of slot item*** and ***event - capable of events***.

```
components={{
        eventWrapper: ({ event, children }) => <div/>,
        event: event => {return <div/>}
}}
```

Thanks for your help!.